# C program/advice to print update-able status in terminal

Tags: c, printing, terminal, carriage-return

I am trying to accomplish the print statements in terminal as follows:

temperature Location 1 = 100 C

temperature Location 2 = 120 C

Where the values can change. So I am not sure how to approach this. Should I try to clear the whole terminal and print again? Return carriage character only clears the most recent line (so for example location 2 line) then how can I change the value of temperature 1? Thanks so much!

Comment: Once you've printed something, it's there. Only the user can clear the terminal. Changing a variable after you've already printed it won't help.

Comment: Many 'terminal' emulators can do cursor-positioning and other such useful stuff, often driven by escape sequences, but their operation is outside the scope of C.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2-line output presents a problem. Generally for handling formatted output on a lines/columns (or x,y) basis, you will want to use a screen output library like `ncurses` to provide some reliable sense of portablility.

Another, much less portable, terminal dependent way to handle cursor positioning is with ANSI-escape sequences. `printf` will interpret ANSI escapes, but not on all terminals, not on all OSs or implementations.

Linux (most vt100 emulations) will handle the ANSI escapes, for Windows, there are different methods for handling escapes between Win10 (Anniversary update) and previous WinX versions. Both are explained at [**Console Virtual Terminal Sequences**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx)

On linux, you can use the `ESC[1A` sequence (written `\033[1A` using *octal* number `033` for the escape or `\0x1b[1A` using *hex* `1b`) to move the cursor up one line (and `'\r'` to move back to the beginning without a linefeed). So the ANSI escape `\r\033[1A` simply moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line and up one. (you can use the same sequence on windows, but how you implement it is windows version dependent -- see the link provided)

A simple implementation to display, e.g.

```
Location 1 = 3.00 C
Location 2 = 37.40 F
```

where the temperatures (actually both lines) are overwritten once each second on Linux could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

double c_to_f (double c)
{
    return c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32;
}

void print_temps (double t1, double t2)
{
    printf ("Location 1 = %.2lf C\nLocation 2 = %.2lf F\r\033[1A",
            t1, t2);
    fflush (stdout);
}

int main (void) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        print_temps (i, c_to_f(i));
        sleep (1);
    }

    printf ("\n\n");     /* tidy up with newlines */

    return 0;
}
```

(where the conversion from `C` to `F` is just done to provide a 2nd temp for location 2)

The code above just updates Location 1 and Location 2 temperature lines once per-second for 4 seconds for temperature `0-3` C. If you are on windows, I leave it to you to follow the link above for your specific version of windows.

Note also, there are additional ways to control cursor provided in the ncurses library, or to a limited extent through `struct termios` provided in `termios.h` and the `tcsetattr` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use "\r" in your printf function to move the cursor to the beginning of the line but i don't think you can print two separate lines which are dynamically updated. Here is the code that suits the most your purposes. In Windows, the sleep function is "Sleep" with a big "S" from file "Windows.h" and in Linux it is "sleep" with a small "s" from "unistd.h"

**WINDOWS**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i<100)
    {
        printf("\rTemperature Location 1 = %d Celsius and Temperature Location 2 = %d Celsius", i, j);
        j=j+2;
        i++;
        Sleep(1000); //sleeps the current thread for 1 sec
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**LINUX**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i<100)
    {
        printf("\rTemperature Location 1 = %d Celsius and Temperature Location 2 = %d Celsius", i, j);
        j=j+2;
        i++;
        sleep(1);  //sleeps the current thread for 1 sec
    }
    return 0;
}
```